# How I Can Add Extra Theme To Sharepoint Performance Point Service

Tags: theme

I use SharePoint 2013.
I want add a extra theme to my SharePoint site.

I use this way for change theme `Site Settings -> Change the look`

How I can download extra theme from internet and load to my SharePoint website ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your onwn [theme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj927174.aspx) by using [SharePoint Designer 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=35491) and the [SharePoint Color Palette Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=38182)

Best way to start is to use an out of the box theme and copy font and color scheme and re-use this scheme.

First copy a font scheme that is closest to your need and rename the scheme.
Font schemes are files with the .spfont extension
You can find the schemes at the following location `All Files > _catalogs > theme > 15`

Second copy a colour scheme that is closest to your need and rename the scheme.
Colour schemes are files with the .spcolor extension
You can find the schemes at the following location `All Files > _catalogs > theme > 15`

Edit your schemes with the [SharePoint Color Palette Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=38182) tool

When your done with your theme save the file and upload to `All Files > _catalogs > theme > 15`, your colour scheme should now appear in the colour dropdown in “change the look”.

A very complete and detailed tutorial you can find [here](http://blog.creative-sharepoint.com/2013/05/creating-a-sharepoint-2013-theme/)

You can also download a few complete themes as WSP [here](http://www.palkotools.com/sharepoint/themes/)